# How to redefine the same command differently over multiple theorems

Tags: environments, tcolorbox, renewcommand

i was wondering if there was a way to renew the `emph` command for each new `newtcbtheorem` you define.

I have the following code already, adapted from an older solution by user egreg. The goal is to match the new color for `emph` with the general color style of the theorem, but it becomes unmanageable the more custom theorems are defined :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mytitlebox/.style={ colframe=#1!80!black }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{definition_}
{Définition}
{mytitlebox=blue}
{def}

\let\oldEmph=\emph
\newenvironment{definition}[3]
  {\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{{\color{blue!80!black}##1}}}%
   \begin{definition_}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
  {\end{definition_}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{propriete}
{Propriété}
{mytitlebox=orange}
{propr}
% Not wanting to copy paste the renewcommand code

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Titre de la définition}{}
Ceci est une \emph{définition}.
\end{definition}

\begin{propriete}{Titre de la propriété}{}
Ceci est une \emph{propriété}.
\end{propriete}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the command is used inside a `tcolorbox` you can use its colors into a command. It can be independent of the specific box

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{
    mytitlebox/.style={ colframe=#1!80!black }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{definition}
{Définition}
{mytitlebox=blue}
{def}

%\let\oldEmph=\emph
%%\newenvironment{definition}[3]
%%  {
%  \renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{{\color{tcbcolframe}##1}}}%
%%   \begin{definition_}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
%%  {\end{definition_}}

\newcommand{\markcolor}[1]{{\bfseries\color{tcbcolframe}#1}}%

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]%
{propriete}
{Propriété}
{mytitlebox=orange}
{propr}
% Not wanting to copy paste the renewcommand code

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}{Titre de la définition}{}
Ceci est une \markcolor{définition}.
\end{definition}

\begin{propriete}{Titre de la propriété}{}
Ceci est une \markcolor{propriété}.
\end{propriete}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you're missing some braces around `\bfseries` and `\color{...}` (look at the full stop after the marked words).

Comment: @campa. You're right! thanks for advertising it. I've updated the answer.